# Transforming list of configuration files to dictionary in Python

Tags: python

I have a basic problem in python. I have this list:

```
['[A]',a,b,c,x,y,'[B]',d,f,'[C]',g,h,e]
```

I would like to transform it into a dictionary:

```
{A:[a,b,c,x,y],B:[d,f],C:[g,h,e]}
```

Does anyone have any elegant idea?
Thank you

Comment: are the chunks always the same size?

Comment: Are they all supposed to be strings?

Comment: What rule is used to determine the key and values - there's several options here: 1) They're equal sized, 2) The key is in a list, 3) The key is anything that's an uppercase letter (if indeed they're strings)

Comment: no they are not always the same size @WeaselFox

Comment: the rule to determine the key is that it's a string as '[someString]'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using the fact the key is in a list, then you can group by list or not, pair up the results and feed them to a `dict`, eg:

```
from itertools import groupby, izip

data = [['A'],'a','b','c',['B'],'d','e','f',['C'],'g','h','e']
grouped = (next(g)[0] if k else list(g) for k, g in groupby(data, lambda L: isinstance(L, list)))
result = dict(izip(*[iter(grouped)] * 2))
#{'A': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'C': ['g', 'h', 'e'], 'B': ['d', 'e', 'f']}
```

Updated based on [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22319701/transforming-list-of-configuration-files-to-dictionary-in-python/22320045#comment33919204_22320045)

> the ... are strings :['[A]','a','b','c','x','y','[B]','d','f','[C]','g','h','e'] and the rule to determine the key is that it's a string as '[someString]'

Change the grouping to utilise a regular expression (adjust as needed), eg:

```
import re

grouped = (k.group(1) if k else list(g) for k, g in groupby(data, re.compile(r'\[(.*?)\]$').match))
```

Comment: thanks for the answer the matter is my keys are not list they are strings : ["[A]",...,"[X]",...,"[Y]",...]

Comment: @user3328690 okay... what other information is missing then... the `...`'s - what are they? Are they objects or strings? Might be simpler if you could provide a real line of code/example data...

Comment: the ... are strings :['[A]','a','b','c','x','y','[B]','d','f','[C]','g','h','e'] and the rule to determine the key is that it's a string as '[someString]'

Comment: @user3328690 I believe that radically changes the question.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the chunks are always the same size, you could write a dictionary comprehension like this (input list is `l`):

```
{l[i][0]: l[i+1:i+4] for i in range(0, len(l), 4)}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the chunk size is dynamic, I would use some assumptions about the types of the config variables in combination with type-checking (which is generally not a very good idea in python, but in this case I think it helps readability):

```
from collections import defaultdict

a = [['A'],'a','b','c',['B'],'d','e','f',['C'],'g','h','e']

grouper = None
config = defaultdict(list)
for x in a:
    if isinstance(x, (list, tuple)):
        # We encountered a list or tuple, so this is a new section
        grouper = x[0]
    else:
        config[grouper].append(x)

print config
```

Result:

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'A': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'B': ['d', 'e', 'f'], 'C': ['g', 'h', 'e']})
```

Answer (score 0):

I know its stupid...
I know.
But it works :)

```
def convert(l):
    keys = [i for i in l if isinstance(i, list)]
    keys_index = [l.index(i) for i in keys]
    keys_index.append(None)
    result = {}
    for i in range(0, len(keys_index)-1):
        result[l[keys_index[i]][0]] = [j for j in l[keys_index[i]+1:keys_index[i+1]]]
    return result
```